# Ghostscript Stamp Image on PDF

Tags: image, pdf, ghostscript, overlap, stamp

Is there any way to stamp or overlap a tiff image on a existing PDF file and output the result using Ghostscript?

I have two PDF which i want to merge in a result PDF with one over the other using ghostscript. I want to know if this can be done and how, or if it may work with one PDF as tiff image on top of the base PDF.

Can ghostscript make this stamp using layers in the PDF?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdfwrite device in Ghostscript doesn't really support layers, so you can't use that. Also its unclear why you think layers would help.

TIFF isn't part of PostScript (or PDF), so you can't directly read a TIFF file into GS. I have elsewhere posted a PostScript program which reads TIFF files and renders them for output. You could use that to read a TIFF file.

However, you would have to mess about with either the PDF interpreter or a custom EndPage procedure in order to read and render the TIFF file. And unless you take specific kinds of action, it will be opaque, which may well not be what you want.

The Ghostscript PDF interpreter doesn't really lend itself to this kind of manipulation, have you considered using pdftk instead ?